# Replacing ID with Corresponding Names from a Different Database

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 databases which contain different information sets and I am basically trying to join the informations based on a criteria.

More exactly. I have 2 databases with the following structure.

```
Table: accounts
------------------------
ID | Username | Password
------------------------
1  | John     | ........
2  | Kyle     | ........
3  | Jenny    | ........
```

---

```
Table: userdata
-------------------------
userid | DataCash | DataLevel
-------------------------
1  | 500 000$ | 100
2  | 999 000$ | 16
3  | 600$     | 53
```

What I basically want to do is save time, a lot of time. By now I've been using manual methods thinking 'I will easily make a query' but in reality it wasn't like that.

So far I would be doing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE userid = X
```

and afterwards

```
SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE id = X
```

yet now as the database grows, it becomes harder and harder to do this manually.
P.S: I'm basically doing this to make a Top5 (and the database is SQLite thus I can't get anything but SQL syntax involved)

I've read it is necessary to use `JOIN` yet so far I couldn't figure out anything. Below is the query I tried running (I belive I am missing something, but I don't know exactly what).

`SELECT userid, key, value FROM userdata JOIN userdata ON id = userdata.userid WHERE LENGTH(value) = 2`

This is a query I pulled out from another question yet I honestly don't understand the way `JOIN` works, even after trying to read the MySQL help page on `JOIN`

To make sure I made myself clear enough as I belive one might loose the track of the question since it spans over so many lines, I want that after running a query to have the following result format:

`Username | DataCash | DataLevel`

So after the joining, it'd take data from accounts, and replace `userid` with `Username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SQL `JOIN` clause is used to combine rows from two tables (on your case), based on a common field between them which are your column `id` in table `accounts` and column `userid` in table `userdata`.

Different types:

- `INNER JOIN` (short name `JOIN`): Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables
- `LEFT JOIN`: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table
- `RIGHT JOIN`: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table
- `FULL JOIN`: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

To find your required output:

```
Select tbl_a.Username, tbl_b.Datacash, tbl_b.DataLevel
From accounts tbl_a    ## <--left side table 
 join userdata tbl_b   ## <--right side table
 on tbl_a.id = tbl_b.userid;
```

Note: tbl_a and tbl_b are table alias name. Giving them a temporary name or short name.